# Can't load data from local storage after publish of a new version

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, local-storage

I use the ProtectedLocalStorage Nuget with blazor server from Microsoft to load and save a serialised object to the local storage but when I publish/deploy a new version my application can't load the object from local storage.

I think that ProtectedLocalStorage uses a key to encrypt the data before saving it to local storage and when I publish a new version the key get's deleted. I think that because I tried to decode the value from the local storage entry but it's only gibberish. I can't find any information in the documentation. Is there a way to not drop the key or is my understanding of the problem correct?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how large is the object you're saving to local-storage?

Comment: the object is about 2KB when saved to a file. The maximum for local storage is 5 MB right ?

Comment: Take a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40862) which seems to be the exact issue you're experiencing.